# Linq to SQL not querying memory

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq for SQL and have always thought that I was querying the results of a Query in memory.  I have just looked at the database and it is showing many thousands of queries rather than 1 which is what I expected.

My approach has been to run a query and then use linq to search within the resultset.

```
        IQueryable<mapping> fieldList = from mm in db.mappings
                        join mi in db.metaItems on mm.secondaryMetaItemId equals mi.metaItemId
                        join mo in db.metaObjects on mi.metaObjectId equals mo.metaObjectId
                        where mm.linkageId == 277
                        select mm;

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            mapping thisVar = fieldList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.primaryItem == info.Name);             
        }
```

How can I stop Linq requerying everytime I access my resultset...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a LINQ query, the query doesn't get actually get executed until you perform an action that actually enumerates over it (deferred execution).  Calling `FirstOrDefault()` is an example of one such method that enumerates over the result (the first result has to be found).  You'll want to call a method or otherwise enumerate over the results once.  That way when you want to refer to those results throughout your program, you do it on a stored copy.

The easiest way you can do that is to convert it to a list.  That will put the results in memory as a list.  You could then use that.

```
IQueryable<mapping> fieldList =
    from mm in db.mappings
    join mi in db.metaItems on mm.secondaryMetaItemId equals mi.metaItemId
    join mo in db.metaObjects on mi.metaObjectId equals mo.metaObjectId
    where mm.linkageId == 277
    select mm;
// save it!
var result = fieldList.ToList(); // query is processed only once here

// do stuff with result
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    // using the stored result
    thisVar = result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.primaryItem == info.Name);             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var fieldList = (from mm in db.mappings
                        join mi in db.metaItems on mm.secondaryMetaItemId equals mi.metaItemId
                        join mo in db.metaObjects on mi.metaObjectId equals mo.metaObjectId
                        where mm.linkageId == 277
                        select mm).AsEnumerable(); 
    foreach (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        mapping thisVar = fieldList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.primaryItem == info.Name);             
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - same behaviour hits database every time.

Comment: @PNC   try to use .ToList() instead of AsEnumerable().  all query result should store in memory.